# why html.onload does not work

Tags: javascript, html

A silly question, I tried code below in chrome browser, there is no output from console, will anyone take a look?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>x</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function onload(){
          console.log('call');
      }
      window.onload= onload;
    </script>
  </head>

  <body >
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Rename  your onload function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>x</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function loadMe(){
          console.log('call');
      }
      window.onload= loadMe;
    </script>
  </head>
  <body >
  </body>
</html>
```

[DEMO window.onload](http://codepen.io/tuga/pen/eNOERa)

but you can also try:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>x</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function loadMe(){
          console.log('call');
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="loadMe();">
  </body>
</html>
```

[DEMO body.onload](http://codepen.io/tuga/pen/Xbragv)

---

**`window.onload` vs `body.onload`**

Use `window.onload` because it is good to separate your structure from the action.

Comment: In your first code the function will execute before onload event, you need to use: `window.onload= loadMe;`

Answer (score 6):

You're in the global scope, and you've named your function `onload`, and as such overwriting the global `window.onload` handler with your function with the same name.

**Rename the function !**

```
function myFunction(){
      console.log('call');
}

window.onload = myFunction;
```